# Swing timer vs Util timer

Tags: java, swing, timer, awt

What is the difference between these two and how do they both function?

I wrote a basic program that moves a circle around when you press the arrow keys and when using the java.util.Timer timer eclipse wanted to remove arguments but with javax.swing.Timer, it worked just fine.

You can't import both Timers so does that mean they are basically just the same thing but different ways of using them?

Comment: You could use both in the same file if you really wanted to, just refer to their full names (i.e. `java.util.Timer`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference is that the Swing timer ensures that events happen on the Event Dispatch Thread. Thread safety in Swing is essential.

For more information, see [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). And a relevant quote from that tutorial about the `java.util.Timer`,

> ...you might use a general-purpose timer if you don't plan on touching
>   the GUI from the timer, or need to perform lengthy processing.

Comment: So Swing timer is just smoother, safer,and more accurate?

Comment: @ImGone98, No (*well, it technically is safer*), it makes sure that whatever UI stuff you do in the timer happens in the EDT.

Comment: `In swing, we recommend using Swing timers rather than general-purpose timers for GUI-related tasks because Swing timers all share the same, pre-existing timer thread and the GUI-related task automatically executes on the event-dispatch thread. However, you might use a general-purpose timer if you don't plan on touching the GUI from the timer, or need to perform lengthy processing.`